# prefer + "-ing" or infinitive

Tags: grammar

> 1. I prefer pork to beef - usual day a day expression.
> 2. I prefer pork rather than beef - less common but grammatically correct.
> 3. I prefer dancing to swimming. - usual day a day expression.
> 4. I prefer dancing rather than swimming - less common but grammatically correct.
> 5. I would prefer to stay home rather than go out tonight - "would prefer" MUST always be followed by the infinitive and not the "-ing" form.
> 6. I prefer to eat candy rather than to eat ice cream - probably the less common but grammatically correct.

I would like to know if my understanding and notion of these sentences is 100 percent accurate, and could perfectly be used by any native speaker if they were to give a presentation on Perfect English Grammar At college.

Answer (score 3):

Well, aside from these specific sentences you make a number of other English mistakes that a native speaker would not make.  For example, the expression is *"day **to** day"* and not *"day **a** day"*.

Otherwise ... You should understand that there are many different English dialects, each of which has its own preferred way to say certain things.  None of these are *wrong*, just different, and an expression that might be common in one dialect might be completely absent from another.  It all depends on who is talking.

All of your sentences are grammatically correct.  None of these is more *common* than any other.

> I prefer dancing to swimming
>   I prefer to dance rather than swim.
>   I prefer to dance rather than to swim.

Some are more wordy, but perhaps the best way to *clearly* say what you mean:

> I prefer to dance the tango rather than to dance the mambo.

"Would prefer", grammatically, is no different from "prefer" in that you can use either the infinitive or the gerund:

> I prefer dancing in the moonlight to doing my taxes.
>   I would prefer dancing in the moonlight to doing my taxes.
>
> I prefer to dance in the moonlight rather than do my taxes.
>   I would prefer to dance in the moonlight rather than do my taxes.

Of course there are many other ways to express a *preference*, and some people prefer never to use the word "prefer" at all.  So I think it's not very useful to say one expression is "less common" than another, but rather understand, from listening to native speakers, in what context each is used.

(Edit) To be clear the "to" in "I prefer to dance rather than (to) swim" is part of the infinitive "to dance" and "to swim" and not part of the expression "prefer to ..."   My point is that you can use either the infinitive or the gerund ("-ing" form) -- both are used equally, although sometimes one *sounds* better than the other.

Comment: Actually, I would prefer is different. If someone offers you tea, to be polite, you would say: I would prefer coffee. Also, the would implies in other context, an imagine situation that has not happened to you before, for example. Musings.

Comment: Hi Lambie. Taking a look at Cambridge dictionary, I found this-Would prefer

We use would prefer or ’d prefer, followed by a to-infinitive or a noun, to talk about present and future preferences:I’d prefer to go by myself.Would you prefer a quieter restaurant?She’d prefer not to drive at night. According to this, Would Prefer is actually followed by to infinitive .now,I'm wondering if this is an AmE BrE thing, or Cambridge corpus use it to convey a genearl idea,though it doesn't look like to me.excuse my mistakes in writing. I'm preparing for the Cambridge Advanced Exam,so I'm just learning

Comment: @Lambie  Yes this is true.  I meant that grammatically they are the same, that you can use either the infinitive or the gerund.  British English might have a "rule" around this but I think it's more that the infinitive *sounds* better (*"I would prefer to answer the question"*) because it includes "prefer to".

Comment: Andrew, Thanks a lot for displaying interrest in my question .as you can see , I'm taking an exam in few months ,so any help is priceless. Just One more thing, if i used the concept of parallelism like -"I prefer studying rather than playing". "I prefer to study rather than to play" in one of my essays ,regardless of the many other ways to convey the same idea, would i be using correct grammar ? All I want is pass this exam!– juan 10 mins ago   delete

Comment: @juan parallelism is about *style* not *grammar*.  It's perfectly grammatical to say "I prefer *to study* rather than *playing* tennis," but it doesn't *sound* as nice.  Unfortunately I have no idea what will be on your exam.  This site is more about learning *natural* English than passing tests.

Comment: Yes Andrew. I looked it up on the net and the definition for parallelism includes many terms which I simply have no idea about.it says something about "Nuances" but I really don't know the concept of that word ,among many others. Bro, could you please  recommend a very useful site where I can find online literature for English learners? Thanks a lot !